# Is it possible to bond two wireless networks to increase the data transfer rate?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, bridge

Is it possible to use two WiFi connections using the in-built wireless adapter and a WiFi dongle, connected to two different networks to be bridged and used in order get a higher download speed?

Any possible method in Windows as well as Ubuntu are welcomed :)

Comment: You say bond and bridged, but you mean bonded. Its possible but the router would have to support the aggregation to get a single logical link, I've never come across that. If you buy AC equipment that supports MIMO it will do what you want with one adapter and AP.

Comment: You can connect to cards to one network and it's called link aggregation. I'm not sure about using two networks. I would assume you wouldn't be able to increase speed but you could have two simultaneous network tasks running at once.

Comment: @Linef4ult I am not clear with your answer. That means it is not possible to do that?

Comment: @ZacAustin Ok? So by doing that I can use each network for separate processes? Can you explain how I should do that?
And I will try seeing how I can carry out link aggregation.

Comment: Sorry but I've only learnt about the principle not the details. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AjithKumar Connecting two regular NICs to one AP wont provide any benefit unless one needs to be dedicated to packet sniffing or similar. The AP can only talk to one NIC/Device at a time. The solution to your issue *is* MIMO.